# Python NumPy Array and Matrix Multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, neural-network

I'm going through the "Make Your Own Neural Networks" book and following through the examples to implement my first NN. I understood the basic concepts and in particular this equation where the output is calculated doing a matrix dot product of the inputs and weights:

```
X = W * I
```

Where X is the output before applying the Sigmoid, W the link weights and I the inputs.

Now in the book, they do have a function that takes in this input as an array and then they translate that array to a 2 dimensional one. My understanding is that, the value of X is calculated like this based on:

```
W = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3
     0.4, 0.5, 0.6
     0.7, 0.8, 0.9]

I = [1
     2
     3]
```

So if I now pass in an array for my inputs like [1,2,3], why is that I need do the following to have it converted to a 2-D array as it is done in the book:

```
inputs = numpy.array(inputs, ndmin=2).T
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Neural Networks typically use a two dimensional array for inputs and outputs with the underlying idea that you have `n` rows representing the observations, and `m` columns representing the features. In your case, you only have `1` feature, your input (which is also what you are trying to predict) and `3` observations. In other words it's more like a convention which happens to be useful for understanding how you use and store data.

Comment: Could you please elaborate that with an answer and an example explanation?

Comment: Imho @TheHalf-BloodPrince already pointed out everything relevant. Perhaps another point which might help is: By asserting that `inputs` are always two-dimensional, you make sure that the orientation of the resulting dot-product `np.dot(W, I)` is **always** a column vector for each feature (each independent variable/combination, etc... has its "own" row), independently of the number of features. F.i. for `n_features=1` and with `ndmin=1`, you'd get a row-vector from `np.dot(W, I)`,

Comment: which on the one hand does not follow conventions, on the other hand posssibly requires transposing etc. depending on the algorithm of the next step.

Comment: Thanks @Scotty1-! I added an answer with further explanations and an example if that can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input here is a one-dimensional list (or a one-dimensional array):

```
I = [1, 2, 3]
```

The idea behind this one-dimensional array is the following: if these numbers represent the width in centimetres of a flower petal, its length, and its weight in grams: your flower petal will have a width of `1cm`,  a length of `2cm`, and a weight of `3g`.

Converting your input `I` to a 2-D array is necessary here for two things:

- first, by default, converting this list to a NumPy array using `numpy.array(inputs)` will yield an array of shape (3,), with the second dimension left undefined. By setting `ndmin=2`, it forces the dimensions to be (3, 1), which allows to not generate any NumPy-related problems, for instance when using matrix multiplication, etc.
- secondly, and perhaps more importantly, as I said in my comment, data in Neural Networks are conventionally stored in arrays this way, under the idea that each row in your array will represent a different feature (so there is a unique *list* for each feature). In other words, it's just a conventional way to say your not confusing apples and pears (in that case, length and weight)

So when you do `inputs = numpy.array(inputs, ndmin=2).T`, you end up with:

```
array([[1],    # width
       [2],    # length
       [3]])   # weight
```

and **not**:

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

Hope it made things a bit clearer!

Comment: I like your answer and thus upvoted, but there is still an error in it: the features are in general in the first dimension but in numpy in the second (axis=1), and the samples in the second but in numpy in the first (axis=0). So if your input contains three features (**and NOT samples**), it will be `I = [[1], [2], [3]]`, resulting in `inputs`: `array([[1, 2, 3]])`, whereas three samples `I = [1, 2, 3]` will result in  `inputs`: `array([[1], [2], [3]])`.

Comment: Well wanted to edit it to add some clarification and now it ended up confusing, because I only added half the edits before SO stopped me from being able to add edits... :D So for clarification: features are stored in the **columns** (axis=1), while samples are stored in the **rows** (axis=0).

Comment: So that means, each row represents one feature? In the example above the first row represents a feature vector consisting of width of different flower petals? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No, assuming you have `n_feats=2` features and `n_smpls=4` samples, then `inputs` will look like `inputs = np.random.rand(n_smpls, n_feats)`. That means, for each of the 4 samples you have 2 features, with the samples being in the rows and the features being in the columns. So if you select `inputs[2, :]` you will get the features of the third samples, and for `inputs[:, 1]` you will get all samples of the second feature.

Comment: Ok so that means, the inputs will be a 4*2 matrix with 4 samples and 2 features?

Comment: Yep, the resulting matrix shape will be `(4, 2)`.